# Updating docker-compose Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I'm working through a tutorial for XGBoost (see: https://github.com/ParrotPrediction/docker-course-xgboost), but am getting an error when running

```
$ docker-compose up
```

That I am fairly sure is caused by an outdated docker-compose version (-v tells me 1.3.1) resulting in an incompatibility with the new version 2 filetype.

However, when running sudo-apt get update, it tells me this is the most recent version (and have tried installing both via pip and the curl instructions on this page curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.8.0/run.sh > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose). pip runs fine, but leaves me with the current version seemingly and after getting permission denied running sudo curl ... I was able to get those instructions to run using sudo sh -c curl ...

I was however, able to update docker-compose to v1.8.0 as the root user using su -i, but those changes aren't carried over to my user account.

Answer (score 2):

I belive you have two issues to address.

1. Mismatch in Docker-compose version requirement for XGBoost

In [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/ParrotPrediction/docker-course-xgboost/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file in XGBoost the format version is clearly defined as version 2. Based on the [Docker Version Reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/)  you require 1.10.0 and above to adhere to docker-compose file format version 2.

You can install the appropriate version using following commands

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/<version>/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Replace *<version>* with the release version you require to install

2. Broken Link to docker-compose

There are many issues reported about version mismatch from root user and non root user when the `docker-compose version` is executed. To resolve issues related, you have a clean setup of docker-compose with following steps in debian based system.

```
#remove any previously installled docker-compose
sudo apt-get purge docker-compose

# Install the version by replacing <version> with appropriate you desire
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/<version>/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

#create a soft link
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

This should solve your problem..